# Android emulator not working in windows 8 beta

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android emulator not working in windows 8 beta. It worked fine on windows 7.

Comment: I suggest you update your graphics drivers and try again running emulator

Comment: what error messgae do you get? What does logcat shows?

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK does not support Windows 8 at the moment. See the [System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that it is working fine for me.

The emulators settings are:
Target = Android 4.0 - API Level 14
CPU/ABI = ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Try not loading from snapshot, and if it doesn't work first time, try again (this is a very frequent issue)

Comment: I set the emulator settings as you said in window 8, But It still not working.